# CS50 python Credit not working for AMEX, working fine with other cards

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, cs50, luhn

```
from cs50 import get_int, get_string


#Asking User For Credit Card Number
def main():
    while True:
        Credit_Card = str(get_int("Enter Credit Card Number: "))
        if Credit_Card !=  "":
            break
        
    cardCheck(cardSum, Credit_Card)

def cardSum(Credit_Card):
    even = 0
    odd = 0


    CC = len(Credit_Card)

    if (CC == 0):
        return 0

    else:
        if (CC % 2 == 0):
            last = int(Credit_Card[-1])
            even += last
            
            return even + cardSum(Credit_Card[:-1])

        else:
            last = int(Credit_Card[-1])
            last = last * 2
            oddDigits = last // 10 + last % 10
            odd += oddDigits
            
            return odd + cardSum(Credit_Card[:-1])

#Checking is card valid or not
def cardCheck(cardSum,Credit_Card):
    Total = cardSum(Credit_Card)

    if (Total % 10 == 0):

        if (len(Credit_Card) == 15) and (int(Credit_Card[0:2]) in [37, 34]):
            print("AMEX")

        elif (len(Credit_Card) == 16) and (int(Credit_Card[:2]) in range(50, 56)):
            print("MASTER CARD")

        elif (len(Credit_Card) in [13, 16]) and (int(Credit_Card[:1]) == 4):
            print("VISA")

        else:
            print("INVALID")
    else:
        print("INVALID")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I cannot figure it out Why my Program is not giving correct output with these **AMEX Card Number:378282246310005 , 371449635398431** In My C implemented credits these two card are showing AMEX
but in python it showing INVALID as output
It's working Fine For Master,Visa

Comment: Can you please explain what does cardSum should do ? Should it just calculate the sum of the card digits ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is your code is using an *absolute* sense of parity instead of a *relative* one.  That is, we start doubling with the second to last digit on the right and then every other digit going left.  But the parity of the indicies of the digits to double depends on whether the original number had an odd or even number of digits.  Your code doesn't account for this.

We need to calculate the parity of the card at the start, and pass this parity throught the recursive `cardSum()` calls, so it doubles the correct digits:

```
def cardSum(digits, parity):
    if not digits:
        return 0

    digit, digits = int(digits[-1]), digits[:-1]

    if len(digits) % 2 == parity:
        digit *= 2
        digit = digit // 10 + digit % 10

    return digit + cardSum(digits, parity)

def cardCheck(cardSum, credit_card):
    checksum = cardSum(credit_card, len(credit_card) % 2)

    if checksum % 10 == 0:

        if len(credit_card) == 15 and int(credit_card[0:2]) in [34, 37]:
            print("AMEX")
        elif len(credit_card) == 16 and int(credit_card[:2]) in range(50, 56):
            print("MASTER CARD")
        elif len(credit_card) in [13, 16] and int(credit_card[:1]) == 4:
            print("VISA")
        else:
            print("INVALID")
    else:
        print("INVALID")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    credit_card = input("Enter Credit Card Number: ")

    if credit_card != "":
        cardCheck(cardSum, credit_card)
```

My guess is this comes up with AMEX because it is an odd length number -- did you test odd length numbers from any other card issuer?

Comment: Ye, My Code is not Working with odd length number